# How can I get ST_Overlap to return single true or false value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I want to know if there is any overlap between `polygon1.the_geom` and `polygon2.the_geom`.  However, I don't want to know for each instance if there is overlap.  Rather, if there is just one overlap anywhere in the `ST_Overlap`, I want one value returned, that being "true." If no overlap occurs, then I want just one value of "false" returned.  Using `ST_Union` to combine results won't work on boolean, that much I know. However, I need to scale my query result down to just one row.

```
SELECT ST_Overlaps(polygon1.the_geom, polygon2.the_geom) from polygon1, polygon2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with PostGIS but you should be able to join on `ST_Overlaps(...)` and see if you get anything:

```
select exists(
    select 1
    from polygon1
    join polygon2 on ST_Overlaps(polygon1.the_geom, polygon2.the_geom)
)
```

JOIN conditions are more versatile than most people think.